# Convert Service Fabric remoting call to REST

Tags: azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-remoting

Currently in our project, we have few Stateless and Stateful services and then we have an API (which is again a Stateless service). Our API service is exposed over http and run of frontEnd Nodes in cluster. Any client from outside hits the WebAPi stateless service, which inturn can call other services via SF remoting. But other services are not exposed over HTTP. and individual services also can call each other via SF remoting.

As a part of a new requirement, there are some other services hosted in other cloud (Openshift) needs to access our Stateless and Stateful services directly (i.e. without the WebAPI service) over REST. I understand that we can expose our Stateless and Stateful services over http, by writing our own custom HttpCommunicationListener (which should implement "ICommunicationListener"). But apart from this I guess, we would need to configure some reverse proxy and Load Balancer stuff etc, to ensure that one URL works for all the requests.

Is this something, which can be achieved. If yes, can somebody points me to any documentation or code sample ?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend having a look at Traefik as a reverse proxy and load balancer.
You can run it as a (containerized) ingress routing service inside the cluster, and direct HTTP calls to your services.

- [Here's](https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/backends/servicefabric/) the documentation.
- [Here's](https://github.com/jjcollinge/traefik-on-service-fabric) how to get started.
- [Here's](https://github.com/loekd/ServiceFabric.Dictionary/tree/master/ServiceFabric.Dictionary.IndexApiService) an example.